# How can I translate $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery); into object oriented Php

Tags: php, mysql

How to convert the mysql_num_fields() to object oriented php for the following code.

```
 $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","john123");
        $objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `cman_tickets`";
        print_r($strSQL);
        //$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `cman_tickets`";
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
        $resultArray = array();
        while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
        {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
                $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
        }

        mysql_close($objConnect);

        echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: what do you mean with convert the mysql_num_fields() to object oriented?

Answer (score 2):

To use object oriented php you have to use mysqli instead of mysql.

```
mysql_num_fields()
```

can be replaced with

```
mysqli_result::$field_count
```

since mysql_* functions are deprecated better avoid that

```
    $objConnect =  new mysqli("localhost","root","john123","mydatabase");
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `cman_tickets`";
    print_r($strSQL);

    $objQuery = $objConnect->query($strSQL);
    $intNumField = $objQuery->field_count; // to get the field count
    $resultArray = array();

    while($obResult = $objQuery->fetch_array())
    {

        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[$objQuery->fetch_field_direct($i)] = $obResult[$i];
         }
         array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
```